# How to apply a filter to only one column in <b-table>

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, vue.js

This question is about  of vue-bootstrap

When I use the filter property of the b-table, 
The filter is applied to all data in the table.
Like below.

```
<b-table
  :items="lists"
  :fields="fields"
  :filter="filter"
  @filtered="onFiltered"
  >


-- Result --

filter : '13'
name  age member_num
John  13  13   
Steve 15  13
Ben   13  17
```

But I only want to apply the filter to the an age column.
Like below.

```
filter : '13'
name  age member_num
John  13  13 
Ben   13  17
```

Comment: Check [this](https://bootstrap-vue.js.org/docs/components/table/#complete-example) example on their website

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a similar issue and solved it this way. please note, my 'lists' is coming frrom store.js
1)create a select input for age filter

```
<b-input-group>
            <b-form-select v-model="agefilter"  :options="this.$store.state.age">                         
               <option slot="first" :value="null">-- اختر --</option>
             </b-form-select>
           </b-input-group>
```

2)Inside computed:

```
 lists() {
            if(this.agefilter!=null)
                 {

                    var filterData = this.$store.getters.lists.filter(data => {
                    return data.age.toString().includes(this.agefilter)
                })
                this.totalRows = filterData.length;
                return filterData; 
                 } else {
                            var filterData =  this.$store.getters.lists
                            this.totalRows = filterData.length;
                            return filterData;
            }
        },
```